# Generate random array float Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im triying to generate a random array of float in start of lenght 25, then using random.range on the start to give a value btwn 1 to 10.

```
public int counter = 0;
public float[] floats = new float[25];
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() 
{
    while (counter < numbers.Length)
    {
        counter++;
    }
        foreach (float value in floats)
    {
        Random.Range(1f, 11f);
        print(floats[counter]);
    }
}
```

Ik im doing smt wrong cuz im triying to use a while there too to count the lenght but... ye... thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Consider not typing in _kiddie speak_.  SO is a site for professionals.  Good luck!

Comment: take pen and paper and think about the logic of your code. you'll quickly find that your operations and control structures do not make any sense. first find out what you want the computer to do. then translate it into code

Comment: besides the basically identical answers below .. for the printing you could format it more nicely using `print(string.Join(',', floats));`

Comment: Idk about the kiddie speak, im actually young also not speaking my lenguage but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign each element of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < floats.Length; i++)
{
   floats[i] = Random.Range(1f, 11f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was triying to use While instead of that one but seems like that is the better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (counter < numbers.Length)
{
   counter++;
}
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

You could just use `counter = numbers.Length -1;` instead of increasing `counter` until it reaches `numbers.Length -1`.

Here:

```
foreach (float value in floats)
{
   Random.Range(1f, 11f);
   print(floats[counter]);
}
```

You traverse over your float array. You do not assign the return value of `Random.Range(1f, 11f);`
You then you then use counter to index your floats array but counter does not change within that loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < floats.Length; i++)
{
   floats[i] = Random.Range(1f, 11f);
}
```